# How fermion doublers cause practical issues?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, lattice-gauge-theory

These days I learn about the lattice gauge theory, and in particular learned when one naively discretizes the fermion action, doublers, superfluous poles for a propagator, emerge. I wonder what issue the doublers cause in practice, and how harmful they are.

On the other hand, these doublers are partially admitted in the staggered fermions to my understanding while they are removed in, e.g., the Wilson fermions. My another question is: does the staggered fermion have its own disadvantage due to the inclusion of the doublers? If so, what it that?

Comment: -Chiral Anomaly: Thank you so much for your comment. For "in practice", what I wanted to mean, for example, pertains to dynamics of QCD. The lattice QCD computation enables one to check whether a theory has a non-trivial infrared fixed point. Provided that we adopt naive fermion with doublers, the obtained result regarding the fixed point is not reliable? Another example is for meson masses. If one again adopts naive fermions, is the obtained spectroscopy different from what is measured in experiments?

Comment: -Chiral Anomaly: Thank you a lot! Then I will also delete the reply to your message later.